# Unexpected loss of performance on dynamically-injected canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, canvas

I'm working on a small project, but I've encountered a strange bug (?) with a canvas injected into the page with Ajax (to be more specific, the jQuery **$('element').load('some_file.html')** method, it just appends the html/text of the file into the specified element).

I have two "modules" that do different things. The first one, which is the subject of my question, is a simple canvas with ~2000 particles moving randomly. 
The structure works as expected, I can switch between the two modules and the DOM is updated without needing to refresh the page.

The problem is that if I switch back and forth between the two projects, the performance of the canvas on the first module is decreasing.

This behavior is unexpected for me, but please tell me if I'm wrong: when loading the template that contains the canvas tag, a new canvas element is created and the pointers to the old canvas and the old array of particles should be replaced.

I tested if my old canvas loops were still running in the background, but it didn't seem like it. I also tried to disable ajax caching and did some tests on the scope of the particles properties, but nothing changed, even with global variables.
I also tried to cancel the requestAnimationFrame, but to no avail.

I'm sorry if I'm not being precise enough, here's a JSFiddle so that you can replicate the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/zq2o5w07/. (Instead of using the load() method, I used html(), and as you can see the performance loss is still happening).

Here's a semi-useless code snippet, as stackoverflow forces me to put one (I'm not gonna put my whole code in here...):

```js
$('a').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#test1') {
        loadTemplate(1);
    } else {
        loadTemplate(2);
    }
});

loadTemplate(1);

function loadTemplate(template) {
    if (template == 1) {
        $('.container').html(' <canvas id="particles-canvas" width="1000" height="400" style="background-color: #000;"></canvas>');
        addParticles();
    } else {
        $('.container').html('<h1>Module 2</h1>');
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Solution: jsfiddle.net/c7zgp8L1. I needed to use cancelAnimationFrame. I tried, but didn't actually used it properly as I was targeting loop and not the "requestId"!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the following two snippets of code:

```
// This code is executed every time a link is clicked
$('a').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#test1') {
        loadTemplate(1);
    } else {
        loadTemplate(2);
    }
});

// This function is also executed everytime a link is clicked
function loadTemplate(template) {
    if (template == 1) {
        $('.container').html('<canvas id="particles-canvas" width="1000" height="400" 
                              style="background-color: #000;"></canvas>');
        addParticles();
    } else {
        $('.container').html('<h1>Module 2</h1>');
    }
}
```

This because jQuery's `.html()` *doesn't remove* the canvas from the DOM. This is a [common issue](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/jquery-html-youre-doing-it-wrong/) because many developers use `.html()` wrong. Read the link for explanation. Instead of `.html()`, you should use `.empty().append()`. This because `.append()` *does* accept DOM elements.

Having said that, it is *much* easier to initialise both Modules in the beginning of your code and then use simply jQuery animations to *show* or *hide* them. For example:

### HTML

```
<a href="#test1">Module 1</a>
    <a href="#test2">Module 2</a>

<div class="container1">
    <canvas id="particles-canvas" width="1000" height="400" style="background-color:#000;">
    </canvas>
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <canvas id="particles-canvas" width="1000" height="400" style="background-color:#000;">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
// Initialisation of Module 1
loadTemplate(1);
addParticles();

// Don't re-build the modules but simply toggle their appearance:
function loadTemplate(template) {
    if (template == 1) {
        $('.container2').fadeOut(function() {
            $('.container1').fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        $('.container1').fadeOut(function() {
            $('.container2').fadeIn();
        });
    }
}
```

## [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/81a3kvcv/)

In addition, the code to generate the particles, `addParticles()`, is flawed. The canvas becomes slower by *itself* after some time! So somewhere in your particle generation code, there is some unexpected behaviour. See this for yourself by looking at the particles for more than 30 seconds.

Comment: I think I already tried emptying it... I'm gonna try and report in 5 mins. EDIT: see http://jsfiddle.net/1e278cvv/, isn't the same performance loss occuring? I also tried to "delete" (the keyword) the loop with a global variable, but its still isn't giving better results, even though it stops the loop when going to the module 2... But if I had 10 modules, wouldn't it be better to load them like I'm doing right now? As for the particles code, I know it is flawed :p. Thanks!

Comment: @TomB: You are clearly seeing it wrong. I fixed your code to make *absolutely sure* that the performance loss is not due to the code for the animations and containers. Therefore, I have asserted that the performance loss is due to your particle code. That is the only remaining problem (one you should be able to solve yourself).

Comment: "But if I had 10 modules, wouldn't it be better to load them like I'm doing right now?" I understand your way of doing it, but if I had multiple canvases, wouldn't it be wiser to use empty().append()? Using hide()/show() isn't really fixing my problem, as the canvas is only being drawn once! I'm gonna see if the particle code really is the cause of the performance loss. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c7zgp8L1/. I needed to use cancelAnimationFrame. I tried, but didn't actually used it properly as I was targeting loop and not the "requestId"! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @TomB The jsFiddle you posted has some strange behaviour. IMO the problem was due to the way you wanted to animate the particles. After a while, they seemed to lose their initial velocity, meaning it might not be a performance issue at all but simply unexpected behaviour of your particle code.

Comment: I just changed the particle script to the bare minimum to see if that was the problem, but the solution is the cancelAnimationFrame. thx again for your help, merci l'ami :)

Comment: @TomB Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer if you feel it anwers your question